# su: Permission denied after removing read, execute bit from others

Tags: docker, dockerfile, permission-denied, alpine-linux, su

I wanted to restrict access of **su** to others but not to my deploy user. So I followed below steps. As you can see su is owned by deploy already but still I am not able to access it.
my docker file is like below:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN set -ex \
 && addgroup -g 1000 deploy \
 && adduser -D -u 1000 -G deploy -s /bin/sh deploy \
 && chown root:deploy /bin/su \
 && chmod u+rws,g+rws,o-rwx /bin/su

USER deploy:nobody
```

Inside container when I execute below commands:

```
/var/www/ $ ls -al /bin/su 
-rwsrws---    1 root     deploy       36560 May 19 11:19 /bin/su

/var/www/ $ su -h
sh: su: Permission denied
```

Note: While I switch from root to deploy like below it works.

```
docker exec -it --user root alpine sh
/var/www/ # su deploy
/var/www/ $ su -h
```

Comment: It doesn't matter: anyone who can get an interactive shell on the container can `docker exec -u` as any user they want to, and for that matter they can trivially get unrestricted root access on the host.  You usually don't need `su` or `sudo` in containers.

Comment: For some reason in my workflow I need su in container. But can you please tell me why it doesn't work. However I figured out passing the same user to docker exec works i.e  `docker exec -it --user deploy debug-test su -h`

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I figured out myself. As my dockerfile runs as USER `deploy:nobody` so wherever I run `docker exec -it alpine sh`, the container run as group `nobody` but the /bin/su is only permitted to root:deploy. :)